# Error TS8022 JSDoc '@extends' is not attached to a class. MyPoject JavaScript Content Files 1 Active

Tags: javascript, typescript, visual-studio

What is this Error:

1. Severity: Error
2. Description: JSDoc '@extends' is not attached to a class.
3. Project: MyProject;
4. File: JavaScript Content Files;
5. Line: 1
6. Suppression State: Active

[image]

Comment: So, no one can help me ( ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am seeing the same thing in some code that I have started looking at.
Looks like it is an error that doesn't prevent compilation.
It seems to relate to a code documentation feature (see https://jsdoc.app/index.html).
The '@extends' is listed as a synonym for '@augments'. Changing all references to the latter and rebuilding the code has removed this error.